# ngbTabet not working while switching to other tab

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using `ngbtabet` (bootstrap 4.0) for creating **signin** and **login** tabs.
By default, the 1st tab is loading. The second tab is not loading when I click on the second tab.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

**1) signin-Container.component.html**

```
 <div class="row">
    <ngb-tabset #tabset>
      <ngb-tab id="tab1" title="Signin">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <p>Signin elements loads here</p>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
      <ngb-tab id="tab2"
               title="Login">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p> Login elements loads here</p>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
  </div>
```

**2) signin-container.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbTabChangeEvent, NgbTabset } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: "signin-container",
  templateUrl: "./signin-container.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./signin-container.component.scss"]
})
export class SigninContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**3) app.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { SigninContainerComponent } from './signin-container.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SigninContainerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
]
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
}
```

Login tab is not loading on tab change?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper in which add login and signin selector in tab content.

Try like this:

```
<ngb-tabset #tabset>
    <ngb-tab id="tab1" title="Signin">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <app-signin-container></app-signin-container>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab id="tab2" title="Login">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <app-login-container></app-login-container>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5m4qjv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: not working. Do i have to add any code of lines min.ts or index.html?

Comment: Check the demo.